# Why do I keep getting the message "Error: arr parameter is initialized." in multi dimensional array?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here, I am trying to loop through a three dimensional array but I keep getting the error message "Parameter is initialized" in array.

```
    int arr[2][2][3] = 
{
{
    {1,2,3},
    {4,5,6}
},
{
    {10,11,12},
    {13,14,15}
}
};
for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++) {
        for(int k=0; k<3; k++) {
            printf("%d\r\n", arr[i][j][k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: careful, having `j<3` in your second for loop is going to index outside `arr`

Comment: is there more code elsewhere in which `arr` is redeclared?

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] that replicates the problem, one that we can copy and try ourselves. Also please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* output of the compiler, And tell us what compiler you're using, its versions, and what flags and options you pass along to it when building. Do it by editing your question.

Comment: my crystal ball says you were trying to put this code in a function but omitted the initial `{` for the function

Answer (score 0):

Declare int i, j, k; outside the loop.
That's probably not allowed in your compiler to declare them in loop.